# Check if a word is the anagram of another recursively in python

Tags: python, recursion

as you can see from the title I should implement a recursive function that checks if two words are anagrams or not. I did it in the "normal" way but I have no idea of how to do it recursively. Here is my code. Please let me know:

```
def are_anagram1(s1, s2):
   return [False, True][sum([ord(x) for x in s1]) == sum([ord(x) for x in s2])]
```

As I said in the title I'm using python

Comment: Actually, the sum of `ord()` calls doesn't guarantee `s1` and `s2` are anagrams of each other.

Comment: Yes but this code (I know seems strange) works...

Comment: No, it doesn't: for example, `"ac"` and `"bb"`.

Comment: Also indexing like that is bonkers; no need to `return [False, True][a == b]`, just `return a == b`. Here's a tip on recursive implementation: if `'gods'` and `'dogs'` are anagrams, so are `'god'` and `'dog'`.

Comment: Ok. You are right. This code does not works

Comment: @pp94: I removed my answer because I don't think it's particularly good. It also has a bug in it. So it seems better to work on this further and see if you can come up with a recursive implementation.

Comment: You should consider adding your solution as an answer to your question. That way, you can mark your own solution as accepted and it will then not linger around in Stackoverflow's unanswered question list. Never update your question with the solution, becauseit makes it harder for people in the future to understand what the problem was.

Comment: Don't put answers in the question. If you have a solution, you can add your own answer (but note that working code isn't particularly helpful if you don't include what the original problem was, what you changed and why).

Comment: Ok @jonrsharpe but if no one is the answer that I'm looking for (anagram with recursion) and I have the solution, what should I have to do?

Comment: **Answer yourself**. But, to make it useful to others, please explain what you've done and why.

Comment: That's what I did. But I did not give an explanation. So, can I do it? In addition I don't understand why my question has a -1. What's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

If you sort then compare the arrays, your algorithm will be much faster. Python's sort runs in O(n log n) time, but to calculate all of the possible permutations and to compare them to the string runs in O(n!) time.

For example, if n is 64, O(n log n) will be constant * 384 iterations. O(n!) will be constant * 1.3 * 10^89 iterations. As you can probably see, 384 iterations is way faster than 1.3*10^89 iterations.

Comment: There is a recursive solution that is O(n^2). Not as good as O(nlgn) but definitely better than n!

Comment: I can't think of a better solution (that doesn't sort the original) than iterating through `word1`, checking if that letter is `in word2`, then removing that letter from `word2` and recursing.

Comment: @AdamSmith your strategy might seem like O(n^2), but it is in reality O(n^3). It's O(n) to remove a letter from a string (you have to copy all parts of the string except the letter and concatenate), O(n) to check the second word for a letter, and O(n) to do this for n letters. Summed, your algorithm runs in O(n^3)

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to pop in with a better solution that recursing. The *canonical* solution to this kind of problem in Python is using [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```
from collections import Counter

words = ['dogs','gods']

def is_anagram(word1, word2):
    return Counter(word1) == Counter(word2)

assert is_anagram(*words)
```

A `collections.Counter` object takes every element in an iterable, assigns them all to keys in a hash map (a dict-like object), and sets the values equal to how many occurances there are of that element in the iterable. It's equivalent to:

```
class Counter(object):

    def __init__(self, iterable):
        self._dict = {}
        self._dictify(iterable)

    def _dictify(self, iterable):
        for element in iterable:
            self._dict.setdefault(element, 0) += 1
```